# How to replace existing form based authentication to adfs 2.0 ? which module to add? How to replace FormsAuthentication class info?

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs2.0, form-authentication

I have existing Form Authentication application as a relying party. I have configured this application as relying party on ADFS server. But ADFS website does not have Form authentication.

What need to be changed on my relying party application?

Comment: A LOT needs to be changed.  You really should read about Federation Authentication.

Comment: Hello, Can you please suggest what and how? Thanks for reply. I am using VS 2010 and WIF 3.5.ADFS does not have form authentication. Now I want to replace my existing RP application FormAuthentication related code like what will be FormsAuthenticationTicket if i dont have form authentication now? and also FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName? Basically I dont know how to use WSFederationAuthentication Module and Session module in code to access cookie and ticket and other related info

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be as good as your question as you haven't provided much background info e.g. Visual Studio version, .NET framework version, asp.net version, etc...

If you happen to be using VS 2010 and [WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291066%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is quite a handy tool called Federation Utility Wizard (FedUtil) that would configure you application "automagically". This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517285.aspx) describes exactly what you need.

In the end, your web.config's identity model should look like the following:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:57349/ClaimsAwareWebSite2/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <federatedAuthentication>
        <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://<specified STS>/FederationPassive/" realm="http://localhost:57349/ClaimsAwareWebSite2/" requireHttps="false" />
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
      <serviceCertificate>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="48BF03FCEDA703DE09E0F1F0CEFED60BB92B3DD8" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
      </serviceCertificate>
      <applicationService>
        <claimTypeRequired>
          <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'http://<specified STS>/Trust'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
          <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
          <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/CommonName" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/EmailAddress" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/webpage" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/title" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/picture" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/manager" optional="true" />-->
          <!--<claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/department" optional="true" />-->
        </claimTypeRequired>
      </applicationService>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="5C8885A8E3D29D6BF6C9365E00B1BEA5EB284D1E" name="CN=<specified STS>, OU=US-Federated Identity, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using VS 2010 and WIF 3.5. I have done with the step above. Now I want to replace my existing FormAuthentication related code like what will be FormsAuthenticationTicket if i dont have form authentication now? and also FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName? Basically I dont know how to use WSFederationAuthentication Module and Session module in code to access cookie and ticket and other related info

Comment: Yes you don't have and you don't need it. If you have setup your app correctly and you are getting redirected to your STS, then the WIF framework will take care of it through SAM and FAM. Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872350.aspx

Comment: Yes Thanks! Can you please also tell should i use FedAuth cookie or .ASPXAuth cookie in relying party? as my existing appliction was Form Authentication but after implementing ADFS my RP web config will be authentication = "None" and adfs/ls project web.config will have "authentication=Windows"

Answer (score 0):

WIF uses WS-Trust or FedAuth to redirect user to ADFS for authentication.
As you are using VS 2010, you should install 
- WIF Runtime 
- WIF SDK for .Net Framework 4.0

Installing the above tools will allow you to use FedUtil wizard to create you claims aware app.

Refer to these articles to start:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/05/13/create-claims-aware-wcf-service-using-wif-on-framework-4-0.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/napegadie_kones_msft_blog/archive/2015/04/03/what-do-i-need-to-build-a-claims-aware-wcf-service-in-vs-2013.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I have done these steps already but this is good article . thanks for sharing!